# Magento 1 - Add image to dropdown menu

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I'm working with a website in Magento 1. I'm new to this kind of project, and therefore I need your help. I have the theme, themevast applied(So I think? I've taken over this project from a partner) to the site and I'm using mega menu. In my menu I have ha dropdown menu for a specific category. In this dropdown I want to be able to have a picture in the bottom of the dropdown, [like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3hye.jpg).

In my manage categories tab [I have these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fDL0.jpg), and everywhere where I'm able to upload images it doesn't show in my dropdown.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh, I'm sorry! Absolutely